# Disposing ObjectContext (per-request) after use

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inversion-of-control

I am using creating one ObjectContext per-request concept. Technically, I am adding ObjectContext instance to HttpContext.Current.Items. But I do not know how to kill this instance properly. Is it safe to use HttpModule and disposing ObjectContext within? I mean, HttpModule might be called for any kind of request. I do not want to use DI/IoC matters, because the project need to lightweight (no third party libs allowed).

UPDATE: here the simple code:
Created a per-request ObjectContext (Entities class)

```
public static class ObjectContextPerRequest
{
    public const string ObjectKey = "_per_request_context_key";

    public static Entities PerRequest
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items[ObjectKey] != null)
            {
                var eContext = new Entities();
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(ObjectKey, eContext);

                return eContext;
            }

            return HttpContext.Current.Items[ObjectKey] as Entities;
        }
    }
}
```

and a disposer module:

```
class ObjectContextManagerModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += (s, e) => { Dispose(); };
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items[ObjectContextPerRequest.ObjectKey] != null)
        {
            var edmx = (ObjectContext)HttpContext.Current.Items[ObjectContextPerRequest.ObjectKey];
            edmx.Dispose();
            edmx = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `SaveChanges()`? And how do you prevent it from being called when an exception has occurred?

Comment: I am using it in repositories. It might be used in several locations (e.g. controller/views). I need to centralize disposing ObjectContext only after all calls finished (like OnResponseEnd). Exception handling is implemented in data layer level.

Comment: @Orif Lightweight has nothing to do with 3rd party libs.  Thats an odd requirement considering there are a lot of great lightweight alternatives to whats included in the .net framework.

Comment: @jfar actually, it is a requirement from my boss to keep the project cleaner.

Comment: @Orif Your boss is an idiot but you probably already new that.  Picking Unity simply because that's the IoC container we use; it's written by and tested by Microsoft and provides a LifetimeManager for exactly what you're trying to achieve here.  Ask your boss if they really think they can write better code than MS.

Comment: @Orif> If this is an internal project, he's wasting company money by making you rewrite things that others have already done (probably better than any of us could individually). If it's a client project, then he's doing them a disservice.  Not relevant to your question, but this requirement really irritates me.

Comment: @Orif "Clean" has nothing to do with 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll be safer to create the context during the BeginRequest and then dispose of it during either EndRequest or ReleaseRequestState (probably EndRequest).  Init is when the module is fired up, Dispose is when the module itself is disposed, and modules don't get created and disposed on every request.

*** UPDATE for comment ***

The module should use its Init method to attach to application events, like so:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication app)
{
   app.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
   app.EndRequest += new EventHandler(OnEndRequest);
}
```

Note that there are other syntaxes available, but that's the one that's documented on MSDN.

This will fire on every request that hits your application.  So if your IIS setup routes static file requests (e.g. images and css files) through the app (which is true for IIS 7 in integrated pipeline mode), then your event handlers need to account for that by not spinning up an ObjectContext instance in cases you don't need one.

*** UPDATE for MVC ***

Since you're using an MVC app, you could also consider doing this in a controller base class or in an actionfilter, using the OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted calls.

As an ActionFilter, you can ensure you apply it only to controllers that need the data context.

Comment: @Paul, do you mean Application_BeginRequest/Application_EndRequest events in Global.asax? If so, these events are fired on every request (e.g. image/css/*.* whatever requested from the client). Initializing/disposing in these events will cause a headache.

Comment: Is your app a Web Forms app, or an MVC app?

Comment: Controller base class is a bad idea, because you can have child actions on different controllers within the same request. Otherwise +1.

Comment: ? how does that make it a bad idea? The logic internal to the base class could check for existence before creating / destroying ;should be pretty safe, no?

Comment: @Paul - Because base controllers, or base anything, is tightly coupled to all of its derived types.  You want to keep any "base" anything as lite as possible.  Its always better to use alternatives to implement orthogonal concerns if available and in MVc there are.

Comment: I agree that a base controller isn't as good as using a filter; that doesn't make it a bad idea by itself.  If most of his controllers need the context, then there's no practical harm in using a base class to do that.  that said, note I was presenting options, not definitive guidance.